# Is it Possible to have an infinite number of divisibility graphs containing $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$?

Tags: graph-theory, divisibility

I came across this post: [How does the divisibility graphs work?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413296/how-does-the-divisibility-graphs-work)

Where you can make a divisibility graph for any number n, using the method in the answer. Is it possible to have a divisibility graph that will always have a $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$?

Comment: What do you mean by "always"? Do you just want some divisibility graph that isn't planar?

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a set of graphs that will always be non-planar. For example the divisibility graph where n=6, and n=8 contain K3,3. Is there a rule or property that could tell me if a graph is non-planar or has K5 or K3,3 for all values of n?